# R: moving values from a dataframe to another when there are matching values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes,

First dataframe is called A:

```
A = data.frame(Col1 = c('2017Q1','2017Q1','2017Q1',
                        '2017Q2','2017Q2','2017Q2',
                        '2017Q3','2017Q3','2017Q3'),
               Col2=c('800256','855625','855450',
                      '800256','855625','855450',
                      '800256','855625','855450'),
               Col3=c(0.4,0.6,0.7,1.2,2.5,3.5,0.2,1.3,1.2))
```

Dataframe A:

```
   Col1  Col2   Col3
1 2017Q1 800256 0.4
2 2017Q1 855625 0.6
3 2017Q1 855450 0.7
4 2017Q2 800256 1.2
5 2017Q2 855625 2.5
6 2017Q2 855450 3.5
7 2017Q3 800256 0.2
8 2017Q3 855625 1.3
9 2017Q3 855450 1.2
```

The second dataframe is called B:

```
B = data.frame(Col2=c('800256','855665','855450',
                      '800285','855625'),
               '2017Q1'=c(0.6,1.2,3.5,0.2,1.3),
               '2017Q2'=c(0.9,1.3,5.6,1.1,2.9),
               '2017Q3'=c(6.5,1.2,4.7,1.1,9.8))
```

**[!!!!]:** In the original B table the name of the last 3 columns is 2017Q1, 2017Q2, and 2017Q3 but if you execute the code above the names of the columns have the form X2017Q1, X2017Q2, and X2017Q3.

Also, dataframe B contains 2 more Col2 values that are not included in dataframe A, 855665 and 800285.

```
   Col2 2017Q1 2017Q2 2017Q3 
1 800256 0.6   0.9    6.5
2 855665 1.2   1.3    1.2
3 855450 3.5   5.6    4.7
4 800285 0.2   1.1    1.1
5 855625 1.3   2.9    9.8
```

What I want to do is create a new column in dataframe A (Col4) that will include the values from columns 2017Q1 to 2017Q3 from dataframe B, only for the matching Col2 values between the two tables, so only for  800256, 855625, and 855450.

Therefore table A will have this final form:

```
   Col1  Col2   Col3 Col4
1 2017Q1 800256 0.4  0.6
2 2017Q1 855625 0.6  1.3
3 2017Q1 855450 0.7  3.5
4 2017Q2 800256 1.2  0.9
5 2017Q2 855625 2.5  2.9
6 2017Q2 855450 3.5  5.6
7 2017Q3 800256 0.2  6.5
8 2017Q3 855625 1.3  9.8
9 2017Q3 855450 1.2  4.7
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default R automatically tries to create valid column names, and numbers are not. You can stop R from doing this with `check.names=FALSE` in your `data.frame` statements.

```
B <- data.frame(Col2=c('800256','855665','855450',
                      '800285','855625'),
               '2017Q1'=c(0.6,1.2,3.5,0.2,1.3),
               '2017Q2'=c(0.9,1.3,5.6,1.1,2.9),
               '2017Q3'=c(6.5,1.2,4.7,1.1,9.8), check.names=FALSE)
require(reshape2)
B2 <- melt(B, id="Col2")
```

Then `merge` where The year/quarter and Col2 are equal

```
 df1 <- merge(A,B2, by.x=c("Col1", "Col2"),by.y=c("variable","Col2"),all.x=TRUE)

names(df1) <- c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")

    Col1   Col2 Col3  Col4
1 2017Q1 800256  0.4   0.6
2 2017Q1 855450  0.7   3.5
3 2017Q1 855625  0.6   1.3
4 2017Q2 800256  1.2   0.9
5 2017Q2 855450  3.5   5.6
6 2017Q2 855625  2.5   2.9
7 2017Q3 800256  0.2   6.5
8 2017Q3 855450  1.2   4.7
9 2017Q3 855625  1.3   9.8
```

Comment: not really, if I do that it will merge the columns 2017Q1 to 2017Q3 too which it will be a mess. It's quite more tricky than that. Thanks though.

Comment: As I said, this looks nothing like the one I want to create. Sorry